# How to gain access to control present in an EXT JS Grid Cell like Checkbox, Combo Box, TextBox etc

Tags: javascript, extjs

Do we have some generic approach in order to access any type of control present in an Ext JS Grid column? For example we have select a value in combobox present in a column of 5 row or select a checkbox etc.

I have been struggling with this issue from quite a long time, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Examples :**

*Grid with Checkbox*
[image: Grid with Check Box]

*Grid with Radio Button*
[image: Grid with Radio Button]

*Grid with Combobox*

[image: Grid with Combo Box]

Comment: Please make an easy to understand example, it's hard to follow you.

Comment: @Alexander, let me elaborate a bit. Lets say we have a grid on which we have a combo box in third column. Now I have to select a value in the combo box of let say fifth row, then how gain access to the combo box. Similarly it can have a checkbox, link or textbox. I hope it clarifies the issue

Comment: It would be great if you do a little example of this grid in jsfiddle or somewhere else

Comment: @Valentjedi.. I am writing a UI Automation Script using JavaScript on Guidewire Policy Center. I am very sorry I don't have access to Ext JS Code. I have attached screenshots of the grid. For automating the website i write scripts like below Ext.GetCmp('component-id').store.getAt(0,1) to access the records. For selecting a value in combobox i need to gain access on the combo control so that i can set the value like this Ext.getCmp('combo-id').setValue('1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

If you want to change the value in a grid programmatically, you change it in the grid's store. The editor is only a little helper for the user.

So what you do is find the store that is bound to the grid:

```
var store = grid.getStore()
```

And you get the first record:

```
var record = store.getAt(0); // zero-based index!
```

Then you get the fifth column:

```
var column = grid.columns.getAt(4); // zero-based index!
```

And the dataIndex (the field that is displayed in the column):

```
var dataIndex = column.dataIndex
```

And then you set the value of the record at that dataIndex:

```
record.set(dataIndex, "myNewValue")
```

If you have to always use e.g. the third value of the combo box, no matter what's inside the combo box, you would have to get the value like this:

```
var combobox = column.getEditor(),
    comboStore = combobox.getStore(),
    comboRecord = comboStore.getAt(2), // zero-based index
    valueField = combobox.valueField,
    value = comboRecord.get(valueField);
```

Comment: Many thank both the solutions are working for me. Can i connect with you on Linkedin (arya,sachin89@gmail.com)